# Handling of reset with multi bit clock domain crossing

Tags: reset, cdc

I have an SoC design with two clock domains, each with it's own asynchronous reset (which roughly means asynchronous assertion of reset and synchronous de-assertion). I am trying to pass a 64 bit signal from clock domain C1 to clock domain C2, which is being handled through an async_fifo with fifo pointers being passed to individual clock domains using gray encoding.

[Refer to this link for details on implementation](https://www.sunburst-design.com/papers/CummingsSNUG2002SJ_FIFO1.pdf)

Let's assume the system wakes out of reset, all fifo pointers are initialized to zero, post that I send 4 transactions through async fifo, which increments the pointer values to 4 on both the side.

At this point, reset is asserted on clock domain C2, which causes read_ptr in async_fifo to go zero, but write pointer is not being reset and still hold the value 4, which results in empty signal going low. At this point my logic starts reading junk data out of FIFO.

One possible solution is to reset both write and read pointers, when one of the domain resets. But this needs reset synchronizer and some more combo logic on reset, and driving reset out of flops, which is not a good practice for DFT.

Is there any other way to handle this?

Comment: Aren't your domain-specific resets driven by a common asynchronous reset? Why would you ever reset only half of your FIFO's logic, and why would you expect it to work correctly if you did?

Comment: Is not resetting the pointer an option?  Or resetting both pointers on either reset?

Comment: @DaveTweed I am not sure what the standard practice here is, but I have a system with memory and compute on different clock domains. Now if something hangs inside compute, I would like to reset just the compute part of chip, without asserting reset on the memory side. Hence I have two different resets, and each might be assert independently of each other in the current design.

Comment: But the FIFO, being the interface between the clock domains, needs to be reset either entirely (both sides) or not at all. In other words, resetting your "compute" doesn't necessarily mean that everything in the compute clock domain needs to be reset. Of course, a far better approach would be to eliminate the "hangs", or figure out a way for "compute" to detect them and recover on its own.